# Apache POI disable auto resize of picture

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to put an image into an Excel sheet.
When I open the file with Excel and I resize manually the cell containing the image, the image gets resized too.

How can I insert a picture into a cell that does not resize depending on the size of the cell?

My code :

```
private void addImageToExcelReport(InputStream is, OutputStream os, File image) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(image))) {
        if (br.readLine() != null) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
            inputStream.close();

            CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
            sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0);

            anchor.setRow1(0);
            anchor.setRow2(1);
            anchor.setCol1(0);
            anchor.setCol2(1);

            drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

            wb.write(os);
            wb.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        loggerService.traceError(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: [ClientAnchor.setAnchorType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.html#setAnchorType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType-) : [ClientAnchor.AnchorType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ClientAnchor.AnchorType.html)

Comment: I've tried using DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE and it still resizes it. My code is pretty much identical with the one in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex Richter suggested, the answer is to set the anchor type.
The following code works for me:

```
private void addImageToExcelReport(InputStream is, OutputStream os, File image) {
    if (image != null) {
        try {
            Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(image);
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

            int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
            inputStream.close();

            CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            Drawing<?> drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
            anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
            sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0);

            anchor.setRow1(0);
            anchor.setRow2(1);
            anchor.setCol1(0);
            anchor.setCol2(1);

            drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

            wb.write(os);
            wb.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            loggerService.traceError(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to have the right librairies. My pom.xml contains these librairies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```